# Redirect after PHP form Submit with ajax not starting sessions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit a `PHP` login for with ajax and redirect to the `header('Location:)'` after submitting the form. But i have searched (well enough i think) and discovered a way to do this is using the `javascript window.location()` but the issue is that after logging in the `session` doesn't start.How can this be solved. Below are my codes.

**Ajax**

```
$('#submit_log').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      username = $('#log_name').val();
      password = $('#log_password').val();
      formData = $('#loginForm').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
          $('.logresult').html('Loading...');
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('.logresult').html('Signing In...');
            window.location = "exporter.php";
        }
      });
      return false;
});
```

**PHP Login Script**

```
session_start();
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if(isset($_POST['log_name']) && isset($_POST['log_password'])) {
    $username = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['log_name']);
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['log_password']);

    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $ret = $sql->execute();

    $count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
    $count->bindParam(1, $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $count_ret = $count->execute();

    if (count($count_ret) == 1)
    {
        while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
        {
            $id = $row['userid'];
            $regas = $row['regas'];
            $uemail = $row['uemail'];
            $pword = $row['pword'];

            if (password_verify($password, $pword))
            {

              $_SESSION['log_id'] = $id;
              $_SESSION['log_name'] = $username;
              $_SESSION['regas'] = $regas;
              $_SESSION['uemail'] = $uemail;
              //header("Location: index.php?log_id=$id");
              echo "Sigining In...";
              exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Information incorrect";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why do you set variables to the username and password and never use them?

Comment: is it redirecting to exporter.php?

Comment: Yes it is but since session is not started, it doesn't login @AshishPatel

Comment: @LucaKiebel i do use them

Comment: but where do you use them?

Comment: Other pages on the site but how can this be the issue? @LucaKiebel

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because in your count query you are checking the password against the username.

```
$count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
$count->bindParam(1, $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$count_ret = $count->execute();
```

should be

```
$count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
$count->bindParam(1, $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$count_ret = $count->execute();
```

But really, you could just leave the counting out and start with the while loop. And move the

```
echo "Information incorrect";
exit();
```

below that. It can't be reached if the login information is correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but the session still doesn't start

Comment: What does exporter.php look like?

Comment: Its a  lot but the begining part `session_start();
error_reporting(0);
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if (!isset($_SESSION['log_name']) || !isset($_SESSION['log_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['regas']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}`

Comment: Log the response you get from your login script to see if the actual login is working. `$('.logresult').html(response);` (and of course, don't do the redirect, yet)

Comment: Wow. It doesn't give any response even when i put a wrong password. Could there be something wrong with the ajax?

Comment: Did you get rid of the count-stuff? Then it looks like it's not finding the username in the database.